# Identify this insect (looks like part of a tree)?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I found this insect and thought it was part of a tree at first, then it moved and so I knew it was an insect. I've never seen it before though so I am posting here hoping someone knows what it is.

[image]
[image]

The location is North East US, during the day, in a tennis court surrounded by trees. The insect was clinging to the cover seen above (which covers the tennis court fence).

Any idea what this insect is called?

Comment: Good pics, clearly some kind of stick insect, someone will know it.  Can you add info about your location etc, as much info as you can as suggested [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info)?

Comment: Not posting as an answer since I am not an expert, but apparently [*Diapheromera femorata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_walkingstick) is the most common species across much of the US.

Comment: Bryan, I think you're right! I just googled "Common walkingstick" based on your link, and under image it shows the same exact one. I will accept an answer once you post it, thanks a million!

Comment: Let's try to draw the attention of @KarlKjer he will know for certain, the details to check...

Comment: It's really hard to identify species with a photo, and I suspect the user just wanted to know it is a walking stick. Thanks for the vote of confidence, but I' not an expert on walking sticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alight, best guess, based on it being the most common species, a decent match in pictures, and a decent match to the description on Wikipedia is [*Diapheromera femorata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_walkingstick), the common walking stick.